# what is Difference between static Sql and dynamic sql?

Tags: mysql, database, mysql-workbench

What is difference between static and dynamic SQL?

I have created database connection for Jvector Map. The code working and set an alert box. Its showing all alert country name canada.

This is my static sql

```
$sql = "SELECT countryId,country, pdogcoregion,ccl,category  FROM countrydetails WHERE Country='canda'";
```

How to change to dynamic any example ?

Answer (score 2):

**Static SQL** is SQL statements in an application that do not change at runtime and, therefore, can be hard-coded into the application.

**Dynamic SQL** is SQL statements that are constructed at runtime

in this case your query is static so to change it into a dynamic one you'd have to construct the query by using variables. and have for example some kinda form for the user to choose their content.

Answer (score 1):

In static SQL, the structure of the statement will remain the same, but with dynamic SQL, it may change.

In your example, you can use a parameter for the country variable to have dynamic SQL.